# JPA count related entities without joining them

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
class X {
  @Id
  int id;
}

@Entity
class Y {
  @Id
  int id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "x_id")
  X x;
}
```

I would like to count distinct values of x_id in y table. I've tried:

```
select count(distinct Y.x) from Y;
```

It works but in sql i get join to x table which is uneccesery:

```
select count(distinct x.id) from y, x where y.x_id = x.id;
```

This join is unnecessary and quite costly for me. Is there any way to avoid it without native query?

Comment: Note that the answer here may be implementation-dependent. Hibernate, for example, might generate a more efficient query.

Comment: I was afraid of this. I use eclipselink

Comment: A JPA solution is that if you don't want the Join to table X, don't map it as a relationship.  You an map the 'x_id' foreign key as a basic to use it in queries without the join..  EclipseLink also has query keys that can be created to use the field in queries as a basic mapping so you can control exactly what you want when you want it.  As for this query, what version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try with `select count(distinct Y.x.id) from Y` (T.x.id instead of Y.x). I am not sure, but intelligent JPA implementation should find out that only id is necessary and would not add the join.

Alternative is to add a int field to Y with a read-only mapping to x_id column:

```
@Entity
class Y {
  @Id
  int id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "x_id")
  X x;

  @Column(name = "x_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
  int xId;
}
```

And the your query would be simply `select count(distinct Y.xId) from Y`

Comment: Works like a charm. I did not realize that I can map one column to multiple fields. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For count inside the JPA repository, you can even use:

Suppose there are two entities: `EntityA` and `EntityB`. If `EntityA` has any relation with `EntityB` then you can use count in your

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_a")
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ea_id")
    private Long eaId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "eb_id")
    private EntityB entityB;
    
    ...
}
```

And another `EntityB`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_b")
public class EntityB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "eb_id")
    private Long ebId;

    ...
}
```

For this, you can use the following method in your `JPARepository` of `EntityA` for getting the count. Remember `_` is the replacement of `.` for method signature in the repository.

```
int countByEntityB_EbId(long ebId);
```